# Postpone the date for moving into a new apartment

Tags: united-states, rent

In Oregon, tenants are usually required to provide a 30-day notice prior to moving out.

My new landlord wants me to move in immediately after my background check. They don't provide a 30-day waiting period prior to moving in. So I will be effectively paying for both apartments for a month.

Is there any way I can persuade the new landlord to start renting apartment as close as possible to the end of 30-day period?

What are the legal means I can leverage to postpone the move-in date? Can I appeal to any statements in a law? The leasing agreement is not signed yet.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it asks how to deal with the effects of the law, not the law itself, and is likely to yield primarily opinion-based answers.

Answer (score 6):

> Is there any way I can persuade the new landlord to start renting apartment as close as possible to the end of 30-day period?

If you already signed a contract with the "immediate move-in" clause, it is going to be difficult to persuade the new landlord. That is because the landlord would have no incentive to postpone his source of income and there is no statute or legal provision available to you on that.

If you have not signed the contract, then you two can still negotiate until either party leaves or you reach an agreement. Under contract law, the latter is referred to as *knowingly and willfully* entering a contract.

Answer (score -1):

> My new landlord wants me to move in immediately after my background
>   check. They don't provide a 30-day waiting period prior to moving in

In most cases there is an Executed Lease Date and a Move-in Date. There is a preferred move-in date that is usually offered. It seems you either declined it or put "No Preference". So they did an immediate move-in date after the Make Ready was complete.

> 30-day notice prior to moving out.

Yes, moving out. Not **in**. This question is a Law Question towards the New place. I do not know what the previous Unit has to do with this one.

> What are the legal means I can leverage to postpone the move-in date

Nothing. This isn't really a Law question. Just a question. No legal issue here. You appear to have committed without thinking about your other Legal obligation to the Previous Apartment Agreement. Having to give 30 days Notice on your other Apartment is not the new Property Management Company's problem.

Comment: please do not judge the author of the question. There was no preferred move-in date offered.

Comment: Then, that is against the Future Tenant to stay committed to obligations of the previous entity. They can deny an application if it's too late of a request for preferred move-in (due to Rent Roll and Vacancy Loss) with a "move in immediately clause"  written in but, it is required to ask. That being said: It still does not disregard the fact they had to give 30 days to the previous Property. You can't say "My previous Property requires 30 days notice, so you have to give me a 30 days Move-in grace period". No, that's not how it works. This is a legal question for the NEW Property. There's none